# George Duckworth's Vergilius?

Tags: vergilius

I am reading an essay on Vergil's Aeneid, and there is a citation that says:
[image: the citation]

Does this citation direct to the book *Vergilius 4* published in 1940, on page 5-17?

If so, I am having trouble finding such a book written by Duckworth.

Comment: Not sure why the picture did not show, here it is: http://imgur.com/a/Xl4JS

Comment: I understand now that Vergilius is a journal. But does the 1940 refer to the edition date? If so, does anyone know where I can access 1940 Vergilius? From JSTOR I only have 1959 -

Comment: Perhaps you could contact the Vergilian Society itself? They may have the early editions of Vergilius in their archives: http://www.vergiliansociety.org/

Comment: If you belong to a university or educational institution, check if you have access to [this file](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=ien.35556008356859). Its the online version of the text in question.

Answer (score 6):

The full citation is: Duckworth, G. W. 1940. "Turnus as a Tragic Character." *Vergilius* 4: 5-17. This is the fourth volume of the journal and was published in 1940.

It seems the article is not available online. *Vergilius* took a hiatus (or had a different name?), and you're right that it's not on JSTOR. There's a collection of the early volumes on Google Books, but it only shows "snippet view" for me.

WorldCat lists [three locations](https://www.worldcat.org/title/vergilius-the-bulletin-of-the-vergilian-society-no-1-6-june-1938-dec-1940/oclc/795275165&referer=brief_results) for the collected volumes, and if you have access to a library that offers InterLibrary Loan, that might be your best bet.

Comment: seems it's tricky to find it. Duckworth taught at Princeton and surely Princeton has it. Classics Collection (Clas). Firestone Call number: PA6825.A2 V4743

Comment: The text is available online [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=ien.35556008356859), but only for members. Chances are that universities with strong classics departments might be members.

Answer (score 5):

I found this is the Cambridge University Library catalogue:

Title: Vergilius.
Other Entries: Vergilian Society.
Published: Atlanta, GA: Vergilian Society, 1956-
Publication history: Began with vol. 1, (1956).
Description: ill ; 23 cm.
ISSN: 0506-7294
Notes: Supersedes Vergilius, no. 1-6, 1938-40.
Continues The Vergilian Digest, 1956-58.
Published by the Vergilian Society.
Subjects: Virgil--Periodicals.